# Fetch Photo in Body response using retrofit library with the help of photo-reference and key

Tags: android, retrofit2, google-places, google-nearby

```
 String photoReference = imageDataObject.getPhotoReference();
            String width = imageDataObject.getWidth();
            String height = imageDataObject.getHeight();
            ApiInterface apiServicePhoto = ApiClient.getClient(GlobalConstant.BASE_URL_PHOTO).create(ApiInterface.class);
            Call<ResponseBody> callPhoto = apiServicePhoto.getSinglePhoto(GlobalConstant.MAX_WIDTH_IMAGE, photoReference, GlobalConstant.API_KEY);
            callPhoto.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: " + response);
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        if (response.body() != null) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: ");
                        }
                        Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.body());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: ");
                }
            });
```

// API INTERFACE

```
  @GET("photo")
    Call<ResponseBody> getSinglePhoto(@Query("maxwidth") Integer maxwidth, @Query("photoreference") String photoreference, @Query("key") String key);
```

// API Client

```
public class ApiClient {
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrlRestro) {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrlRestro)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
```

//Base URL

```
public static final String BASE_URL_PHOTO = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/";
```

**I am trying this code but i am unable to get anything in response body. Body always null. Is there any way to get photo using photo reference.**

Thank You in Advance

Comment: Make sure that places API is enabled in the developer console. or use Glide/ Picasso for image download

Comment: @MuraliPrajapati Yes, place API is enabled in the developer console. I am using Picasso for download. But the response body contained null value. If get a sample code then also good. Thank You!!

Comment: I tried this api in postman it is working fine there. use photoreference given by google here:https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos

Comment: Ok I will try once more.

Comment: I tried it on my pc using Glide and it is working fine with google's photo reference and I am not clear why are you using Retrofit for image download

Comment: @Murali Prajapati Thank You. Glide is much better than other. Thank You!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Glide is working fine for me. I'm posting the code here for you.

```
ImageView ivPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivPhoto);
String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo" +
    "?maxwidth=400" +
    "&photoreference=CnRtAAAATLZNl354RwP_9UKbQ_5Psy40texXePv4oAlgP4qNEkdIrkyse7rPXYGd9D_Uj1rVsQdWT4oRz4QrYAJNpFX7rzqqMlZw2h2E2y5IKMUZ7ouD_SlcHxYq1yL4KbKUv3qtWgTK0A6QbGh87GB3sscrHRIQiG2RrmU_jF4tENr9wGS_YxoUSSDrYjWmrNfeEHSGSc3FyhNLlBU" +
    "&key=AIzaSyAfDHQhe4fmz5FAitOnTjrOFPesb88GXFE";  

Glide.with(this)
    .load(url)
    .into(ivPhoto);
```